# markdown to put a box around text in a comment

Tags: support, comments, design, markdown

[This comment](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/44720/does-anything-ever-get-absolutely-deleted-i-e-so-that-it-is-impossible-to-ret#comment91287_44723) displays with a box around some of the text.

> [image]

Firefox and Safari both display it this way.

**What is the markdown code to create such a box?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**That's not markdown, but mis-rendered (La)TeX code.**

To make MathJax render LaTeX code in math mode, you have to enclose the code between two $ signs. That comment was using two dollar signs for [grawlixes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grawlix), and since https://cs.stackexchange.com/ has MathJax "on", that's what you see.

Comment: Oh, thank you for introducing me to the word "grawlix".  That alone was worth asking the question.